# How to delete stale customized Ocean objects

Tags: ocean

I am in the process of implementing a customized DataSource. Since I am making changes to the serialization mechanism, I get a lot of stale object entries (the objects could not be read from the data source) in my input data tree when restarting the project. How can I remove these objects from the input tree, the normal delete function does not work on these objects.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a solution just through the Petrel user interface. Make sure that none of the components trying to resolve the objects are loaded (change the Petrel configuration to not load the modules, remove them from the probing path).

When these objects are entirely unknown and unresolvable, the right mouse button will offer a delete option. Executing the delete will remove the item from the tree.

For the general handling of object serialization (and upgrades) see the Ocean.chm help file, section Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Data Namespace. Here you will find further hints and services.

Answer (score 1):

Ocean is platform produced by Schlumberger for building plugins for their software products, most notably Petrel - a geology modeling program.

As for removing the objects from the input tree, I think the code may be:

`Slb.Ocean.Petrel.PetrelProject.PrimaryProject.Extensions.Remove(objectToRemove);`

According to the SLB training course, you do the opposite (`Extensions.Add()`) to add customized objects to the tree.

Comment: Something else I remembered after I posted this is that you can explicitly make objects deletable by making your object implement the IDeletable interface.  You don't actaully have to do do anything inside the interface methods; as long as you have them, Ocean will handle the actual deletion.  You do have to instantiate the object you return from DeletableInfo with the arg set to true, though.

Answer (score 0):

To delete customized DataSource still in development, you can go directly to your project and physically delete it.

For example, if remove:
myPetrelProject**.ptd\Ocean\myPersistence.bxml**

The next time you open the project, the object will not appears.